# How to iterate throught attributes' names in xml version="1.0"

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to iterate through attributes' names in xml version="1.0"
A Reference XML provides me extra attribute values to be manipulated in a double for-each mainly by their index positions. I found a solution through successive xsl:if, however it is not suitable for many items. Please have a look in the following code and propose something.
Thank you in advance.

Here is MyMainXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="koinohrista.xsl"?>
 <Features>
 <date>April 2022</date>
  <Feature code="A" info="Common Expenses" name="Garden" price="110.00"></Feature>
  <Feature code="A" info="Common Expenses" name="Cleaning" price="90.00"></Feature>
  <Feature code="B" info="Elevator Expenses" name="Maintainance" price="49.00"></Feature>
  <Feature code="C" info="Extra Costs" name="Painting" price="321.50"></Feature>
  <Feature code="D" info="Proriator Expenses" name="Repairing" price="356.60"></Feature>
  <Feature code="E" info="Heating Expenses" name="Petrol" price="2621.53"></Feature>
 </Features>
```

Here is MyReferencing XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hiliosta.xsl"?>
 <Features>
  <Feature name="A1" koinoh="58.20" elev="38.60" heat="62.00" pagio="17.98"></Feature>
  <Feature name="A2" koinoh="45.50" elev="29.45" heat="45.00" pagio="11.25"></Feature>
  <Feature name="A3" koinoh="63.80" elev="39.60" heat="62.00" pagio="17.90"></Feature>
  <Feature name="B1" koinoh="60.00" elev="47.75" heat="62.00" pagio="24.18"></Feature>
  <Feature name="B" koinoh="46.40" elev="36.30" heat="45.00" pagio="15.75"></Feature>
 </Features>
```

Here is MyXSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="Hiliosta" select="document('C:\Kapopoulos\Hiliosta.xml')"/>    
  <xsl:key name="KeyCode" match="Feature" use="@code"/>
 <xsl:template match="Features">
  <html>
   <body>
    <table class="margin" border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="30">
     <tr>
      <th width="48%" bgcolor="#D7E7F7" align="center"><b>Expenses Description per Category</b></th>
      <th width="52%" bgcolor="#D5E9D7" align="center"><b>Expenses Description per Appartment</b></th>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <xsl:for-each select="Feature[generate-id() = generate-id(key('KeyCode',@code)[1])]">   
      <xsl:sort select="@code" order="ascending"/>
     <table class="margin" border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="50">
      <tr>
       <td colspan="6" align="center"><b>Category 
       <xsl:value-of select="@code"/> (<xsl:value-of select="@info"/>)</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#D7E7F7">
       <th align="center" width="24%">Description:</th>
       <th align="center" width="24%">Cost:</th>
       <th align="center" width="13%" bgcolor="#D5E9D7">Expenses</th>
       <th align="center" width="13%" bgcolor="#D5E9D7">Total.mil</th>
       <th align="center" width="13%" bgcolor="#D5E9D7">Appart.mil</th>
       <th align="center" width="13%" bgcolor="#D5E9D7">Cost</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('KeyCode',@code)">
       <xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[@name = current()/@name])">
        <tr>
         <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
         <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="@price"/></td> 
         <xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[@code = current()/@code])">
           <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyCode',@code)/@price)"/></td>           


<!-- GET RID OF FOLLOWING REPETITIONS -->
            <xsl:if test="@code='A' or @code='C' or @code='D'"> 
             <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum($Hiliosta//Feature/@koinoh)"/></td>
             <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="$Hiliosta/*/Feature[@name='A1']/@koinoh"/></td>
             <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('KeyCode',@code)/@price) 
              * $Hiliosta/*/Feature[@name='A1']/@koinoh div sum($Hiliosta//Feature/@koinoh),'0.00')"/></td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@code='B'"> 
             <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum($Hiliosta//Feature/@elev)"/></td>
             <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="$Hiliosta/*/Feature[@name='A1']/@elev"/></td>
             <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('KeyCode',@code)/@price) 
              * $Hiliosta/*/Feature[@name='A1']/@elev div sum($Hiliosta//Feature/@elev),'0.00')"/></td>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@code='E'"> 
             <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum($Hiliosta//Feature/@heat)"/></td>
             <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="$Hiliosta/*/Feature[@name='A1']/@heat"/></td>
             <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('KeyCode',@code)/@price) 
              * $Hiliosta/*/Feature[@name='A1']/@heat div sum($Hiliosta//Feature/@heat),'0.00')"/></td>
            </xsl:if>       
<!-- GET RID OF PREVIOUS REPETITIONS -->    
            

          </xsl:if>
        </tr> 
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="1" align="center"><b>Total: </b></td>
       <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyCode',@code)/@price)"/></td>
      </tr>
     <br/>
     </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
     <br/>
    <table class="margin" border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="48%" height="35">  
     <tr bgcolor="#D7E7F7">
      <td align="center" width="24%" colspan="1"><b>Grand Total:</b></td>
      <td align="center" width="24%" ><xsl:value-of select="sum(//Feature/@price)"/></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </body>    
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what is it that you are trying to accomplish here and add the expected output. Reducing the code to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem would also be helpful - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In xslt 1.0 you can use variables for this like this:

```
<xsl:if test="not(preceding::*[@code = current()/@code])">
  <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('KeyCode',@code)/@price)"/></td> 
  
  <xsl:variable name="attributeName">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@code='A' or @code='C' or @code='D'">koinoh</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@code='B'">elev</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="@code='E'">heat</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum($Hiliosta//Feature/@*[name()=$attributeName])"/></td>
  <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="$Hiliosta/*/Feature[@name='A1']/@*[name()=$attributeName]"/></td>
  <td rowspan="{count(key('KeyCode',@code))}" align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('KeyCode',@code)/@price) 
    * $Hiliosta/*/Feature[@name='A1']/@*[name()=$attributeName] div sum($Hiliosta//Feature/@*[name()=$attributeName]),'0.00')"/></td>
  
</xsl:if>
```